# Angular, ng-templates with if condition

Tags: html, angular, angular-ng-if, angular-template

I want to call for two separate templates according to role id changes. I can get my role which role as

```
ngIf="rolet.role.id== adminRoleId
```

two templates are,

```
<ng-template #role ></ng-template>
```

and

```
<ng-template #admin ></ng-template>
```

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitchCase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really don't know how many role in your project. But if you want to use two ng-template,check and test with the following code.

```
<div *ngIf="ngIf="rolet.role.id== adminRoleId; then #role else #admin"></div>
<ng-template #role>
  ...
</ng-template>
<ng-template #admin>
  ....
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can always use a switch case.
It's faster and say cleaner (personal opinion)

```
<div [ngSwitch]="num">
      <div *ngSwitchCase="'1'">One</div>
      <div *ngSwitchCase="'2'">Two</div>
      <div *ngSwitchCase="'3'">Three</div>
      <div *ngSwitchCase="'4'">Four</div>
      <div *ngSwitchCase="'5'">Five</div>
      <div *ngSwitchDefault>This is Default</div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I put them in separate div tags  like this

```
 <div *ngIf="rolet.role.id== adminRoleId">
  <ng-template #adimn></ng-template>
</div>

 <div *ngIf="rolet.role.id!= adminRoleId">
  <ng-template #role></ng-template>
</div>
```